# Binding several keys to one yasnippet

Tags: key-bindings, yasnippet, keyboard-layout

Suppose we have a snippet for sql mode:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: select *
# key: sel
# --
SELECT ${1:*} FROM $2;
```

Sometimes I forget to switch the keyboard layout and type Russian "ыуд" instead of "sel". I tried this:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: select *
# key: sel
# key: ыуд
# --
SELECT ${1:*} FROM $2;
```

Here `ыуд` works, but `sel` doesn't. Is creating a second yasnippet with different key the only possibility to fix the issue? Or there is a way to bind the snippet to several keys?

Also is it possible to switch the keyboard layout when `ыуд` snippet is activated? Maybe, we'll need to make call to the operating system?

Comment: It's an open FR (from 2011!): https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/114 there's also this for regex support https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/988

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two snippets with different names and different trigger keys but the same expansion.

So name the first one (for example) 'sel':

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: sel
# key: sel
# --
SELECT ${1:*} FROM $2;
```

and the second one 'ыуд':

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: ыуд
# key: ыуд
# --
SELECT ${1:*} FROM $2;
```

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it were elaborated a bit - perhaps with an example.

Comment: You're right, of course. I'll come back and do it when I have time.